# Clear the contents on accordion header clicks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have the accordion that provides search by name and Id options. I would like to clear the textboxs when the acccordion header is clicked...

eg. If I opt search by ID, Then if any text is present in the Name should be cleared.

Below is my code,

```
    <div id="accordion" style="width: auto; height: auto">

         <h3>
        <a href="#">Search by Name </a>
     </h3>
    <fieldset>
      // Text box for name 

    </fieldset>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Search by Id</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
             // Text box for ID
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

// SUBMIT BUTTON

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var icons = {
            header: "ui-icon-circle-triangle-e",
            headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-triangle-s"
        };

        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();

        });

        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                collapsible: false,
                autoHeight: true,
                fillSpace: true,
                icons: icons
            });

        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting as I do not see any code that tries to clear the boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ui.oldContent.find(":input").val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`changestart`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-changestart) event, which you can provide an event handler for and perform the necessary `input`-clearing code:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    changestart: function (event, ui) {
        ui.newContent.find(":input").val('');
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/vq9t3/

Comment: @ Andrew Whitaker. Sorry I have a confusion here. I am using MVC frame work. But At the controller end I still see that the old values are retained.[Eg Input by Search by ID remains though I enter an input in the Name . Both values are sent to the Controller]

Comment: @Mermaid: Interesting, I will take a look.

Comment: @ AndrewWhitaker Eureka... I found it ... I realized that we need to explicitly capture the active index and based  on the active index I have cleared the inputs for the div tags